# How to remove dynamically added style block

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Following Style block keep on adding to the shortlisted basket when user click on the add button. Also I want to remove Whole Style block when it comes to Delete option

```
$('<style type="text/css" id="myEffect">' + 
            '.ui-effects-transfer { background: url('+thumbnailImg+')  no-repeat; }' +
            '</style>').appendTo('.shortListed-Basket');
```

I tried `$('#myEffect').remove();` But its not working. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Just remove the code?  If that doesn't work, did you put `$('#myEffect').remove();` *after* the style block? It can only remove it, if it already exists.

Comment: Are you adding this block multiple times? IDs are assumed to be unique, and `$('#myEffect')` will only find the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment:

*Style block keep on adding to the shortlisted basket when user click on the add button*

```
 $('<style type="text/css" id="myEffect">' + 
    '.ui-effects-transfer { background: url('+thumbnailImg+')  no-repeat; }' +
    '</style>').appendTo('.shortListed-Basket');
```

This explains that you are adding multiple style blocks with same id, that is not valid because in a single page you have to use unique ids. so there are two ways either apply unique ids by adding some kind of increment number like `id1, id2, ...` or change the id to classname like `id="myEffect"` change to `class="myEffect"`.

So now you can try this:

```
 $('<style type="text/css" class="myEffect">' +
    '.ui-effects-transfer { background: url('+thumbnailImg+')  no-repeat; }' +
    '</style>').appendTo('.shortListed-Basket');
```

now if you want to remove this style then use this:

```
$('.shortListed-Basket').find('.myEffect').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

Only add the block if it doesn't already exist:

```
if ($("#myEffect").length == 0) {
    $('<style type="text/css" id="myEffect">' + 
        '.ui-effects-transfer { background: url('+thumbnailImg+')  no-repeat; }' +
        '</style>').appendTo('.shortListed-Basket');
}
```

Then you should be able to remove it with:

```
$("#myEffect").remove();
```

Comment: I tried your code. Its working. But how to set the ids dynamically. if I add $("#myEffect").remove(); it will affect to all. Can you please help me. I have asked this question in 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521211/jquery-transfer-effect-in-ng-repeat

Comment: What do you mean "it will affect to all"? There's only one block with that ID. Do you mean the CSS changes affect all elements with `ui-effects-transfer` class? If you want to set the style of specific elements, you should use a more specific selector in the CSS. Or just use the jQuery `.css()` method to set the style of the specific elements directly, instead of adding style blocks.

Comment: Adding and removing style blocks is an unusual way of updating things. What you usually do is create a single set of CSS, and then add and remove classes from elements so that they pick up the appropriate styles.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are triggering the `$('#myEffect').remove();` when the script is loaded and your DOM contains the style block, I tried the same thing and the style tag was successfully deleted when I ran `$('#myEffect').remove();` from console

```
<div class="shortListed-Basket"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var thumbnailImg = "test";
$('<style type="text/css" id="myEffect">' + 
            '.ui-effects-transfer { background: url('+thumbnailImg+')  no-repeat; }' +
            '</style>').appendTo('.shortListed-Basket');
</script>
```